# Copying the most recent file on a server to a local directory

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to figure out how to copy the most recent file in a server directory to a local directory in c#.

I am needing to do this to over 100 directories.  They will all copy and rename to the same local directory.

The directories all named: e.g. \ServerPath\01, \ServerPath\02, \ServerPath\03, etc.

Right now I have a batch script that will do it but it takes forever since it goes through each and every file in each directory.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought was "Is this possible with Robocopy??" I did a quick search on Google for "Robocopy most recent file" and came up with a [blog post](http://sirsql.net/blog/2011/7/6/grabbing-the-newest-file-from-subdirectories-using-powershel.html) about handling this with a powershell script.

This should at least provide you the latest files without you having to go through "...each and every file in each directory".

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.  This is much, much quicker.  The only problem is that there are other sub-directories in that main directory that I do not want to pull from.  But that script is a great start.

Comment: No probs. I've only started using Robocopy in the past year or so, but I think its a great tool. The powershell script was just something else I stumbled on, but I'm glad it is of some use.